# Not all my scripts are enqueueing

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

From both scripts, only 'custom.js' is loaded, not common.js

this is in my functions.php file:

```
<?php
function custom_scripts () {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');


        wp_enqueue_script('common', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/common.js', array(), '1.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.1', true );

        wp_enqueue_script('common');
        wp_enqueue_script('custom');
    }
}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "custom_scripts");
?>
```

any idea whyy?

Comment: Is it not *working*? Or not being loaded at all? There's no script tag in the document at all? Also, `wp_enqueue_scripts` doesn't run in the admin, so `! is_admin()` is redundant.

Comment: Try to change handler **(common)** name.

Comment: @PratikPatel That worked, didn't know it was a reserved word. is it?

Comment: Yes may be its reserved word so thats why your script not load.

Comment: Well. Perhaps you want to add an answer that i can accept or else i'm deleting the question. Thanks anyways!

Comment: `common` is [used from WordPress itself](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L82). Though I usually advise for deleting questions, I think you should not in this case and let @PratikPatel write up an answer. Feels like this could be important for future visitors (with my comment I wanted to provide the link for where WP uses this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to change handler `common` name.